# OR Operation in JOINS SQL(MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Am using MYSQL

```
SELECT m.proposalId, m.title, n.stageNumber, n.committeeId, n.modifiedDate, o.msNumber , o.description,o.ics,o.edition FROM mystands_Proposal m 
INNER join  
    mystands_ProjectLifecycle n on m.proposalId = n.proposalId 
INNER join  
    mystands_Project o on m.proposalId = o.proposalId 
WHERE 
    n.newState=0  AND n.committeeId=79827 AND (n.assignedTo=29913 OR n.actionBy=29913) AND n.proposalId LIKE '%sdas%' AND o.projectNumber LIKE '%sdass%' AND n.stageNumber=40.92 AND o.category=1 AND o.degreeofCorrespondence=1 AND o.msNumber LIKE '%sdas%' AND (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-15' AND n.stageNumber=40.2) AND (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-07' AND n.stageNumber=30.99) AND (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-27' AND n.stageNumber=55.99)
```

I doing inner join for three tables for search functionality and in java if the user enters the values then am appending the value to sql query on the fly The above code is working fine for AND operations between fields.

How do I perform "OR"  operation for the fields entered by user and display result 
Actually If I have tried with this

```
SELECT m.proposalId, m.title, n.stageNumber, n.committeeId, n.modifiedDate, o.msNumber , o.description,o.ics,o.edition FROM mystands_Proposal m 
INNER join  
    mystands_ProjectLifecycle n on m.proposalId = n.proposalId 
INNER join
    mystands_Project o on m.proposalId = o.proposalId  
WHERE 
    n.newState=0      OR n.committeeId=80246 OR (n.assignedTo=79977 OR n.actionBy=79977) OR n.proposalId LIKE '%ads%' OR o.projectNumber LIKE '%sds%' OR n.stageNumber=30.99 OR o.category=1 OR o.degreeofCorrespondence=1 OR o.msNumber LIKE '%sadsa%' OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=40.2) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=30.99) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-29' AND n.stageNumber=55.99)
```

Now what is happening is it is giving me the results of inner joins because newState=0 is true and whole where condition is getting true and am getting the results of inner joins on three table and the result is not getting filtered as desired

Can you please help where am going wrong
Thanks

Comment: You need to put the parentheses in the right place to get the logic you want.  It is unclear why your `where` condition is not what you really want, given what you describe in the text.

Comment: Hi Gordon here if the user enters values in the search form then am appending that in where clause after newState=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are getting everything because newstate = 0 is always true then you just need to put this, if I am misunderstanding then I apologise but this seems to be the problem as I understand it:

> "because newState=0 is true and whole where condition is getting true"

```
n.newState=0 AND (n.committeeId=80246 OR (n.assignedTo=79977 OR n.actionBy=79977) OR n.proposalId LIKE '%ads%' OR o.projectNumber LIKE '%sds%' OR n.stageNumber=30.99 OR o.category=1 OR o.degreeofCorrespondence=1 OR o.msNumber LIKE '%sadsa%' OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=40.2) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=30.99) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-29' AND n.stageNumber=55.99))
```

Somewhere in your code keep a record of how many where conditions you have added and if it is larger than 0 add the 'AND ( ...... ) as I don't know what your code that generates this query looks like I can't help you any further

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
n.newState=0
    AND (
    n.committeeId=80246 OR (n.assignedTo=79977 OR n.actionBy=79977) OR n.proposalId LIKE '%ads%' OR o.projectNumber LIKE '%sds%' OR n.stageNumber=30.99 OR o.category=1 OR o.degreeofCorrespondence=1 OR o.msNumber LIKE '%sadsa%' OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=40.2) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=30.99) OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-29' AND n.stageNumber=55.99)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is your goal. If you can provide sqlfiddle with data sample and expected result it would help a lot.

Generally speaking and from my expirience usually you should have something like:

```
SELECT 
  m.proposalId, m.title, 
  n.stageNumber, n.committeeId, n.modifiedDate, 
  o.msNumber , o.description,o.ics,o.edition 
FROM mystands_Proposal m 
INNER join  
    mystands_ProjectLifecycle n 
ON m.proposalId = n.proposalId 
   AND n.newState=0
   AND ( n.committeeId=80246 
        OR n.assignedTo=79977 
        OR n.actionBy=79977
        OR n.proposalId LIKE '%ads%'
        OR n.stageNumber=30.99
        OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=40.2) 
        OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-22' AND n.stageNumber=30.99) 
        OR (n.modifiedDate <='2015-05-29' AND n.stageNumber=55.99)
   )
INNER join
    mystands_Project o 
ON m.proposalId = o.proposalId  
   AND ( o.projectNumber LIKE '%sds%' 
        OR o.category=1
        OR o.degreeofCorrespondence=1 
        OR o.msNumber LIKE '%sadsa%')
```